# I have "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter does not exist" exception when I try to use CostumSql in Liferay 7.1

Tags: java, sql, exception, liferay

I try to use CostumSql, but I get the following Exception:

> Caused by:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter does not exist

This is my Finder:

```
Session session = null;
try {
    session = openSession();

    String sql = _customSQL.get(getClass(),FIND_BY_KEYWORDS);

    SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    q.setCacheable(false);
    q.addEntity("BlockchainAccount",BlockchainAccountImpl.class);

    QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(q);
    qPos.add(companyId);
    qPos.add(groupId);
    qPos.add(keywords);

    return (List<BlockchainAccount>) QueryUtil.list(
                        q, getDialect(), start, end);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        throw new SystemException(e);
    }
    catch (SystemException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
finally {
    closeSession(session);
}

return null;
```

Comment: `CostumSql` or `CustomSql`?

Comment: :) now here's the next project name for an SQL-interface to a NoSQL DB. I'd be interested in what `sql` is - please post the underlying statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936856/like-in-sql-not-work-i-dont-understand-why 
now it not work with LIKE. If i use the whole keywords it works, if  i try to use sql with LIKE, not work.